# Geocode multiple addresses with React

Tags: reactjs, promise, async-await, react-native, google-geocoder

I am using the `react-native-geocoder` package to geocode multiple adresses. The problem is that apparently my code has some issue with batch requests.

Why the code works for individual requests and not for batch requests and is there a way to get around this error?

```
async getLocations(locations) {
  Geocoder.fallbackToGoogle(GEOCODE_API_KEY);
  this.setState({
    annotations: await Promise.all(locations.map(this.getLocation))
  });
}

async getLocation(location) {
  try {
    let res = await Geocoder.geocodeAddress(location.address);
    console.log("RESULT:", location.address, await res[0].position);
    return (
      {
        latitude: await res[0].position.lat,
        longitude: await res[0].position.lng,
        title: location.provider,
        subtitle: location.address,
      }
    );
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Error fetching geodata:", err);
  }
  return null;
}
```

result (only last request working):

```
Error fetching geodata Error: geocodePosition failed(…)
Error fetching geodata Error: geocodePosition failed(…)
Error fetching geodata Error: geocodePosition failed(…)
Error fetching geodata Error: geocodePosition failed(…)
Error fetching geodata Error: geocodePosition failed(…)
RESULT getLocationPosition Object {lat: 22.544028, lng: 19.124154}
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Cannot read property 'id' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
    at http://hostserver/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=true:35937:11
    at Array.map (native)
    at Constructor.render (http://hostserver/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=true:35928:38)
    at Constructor.proxiedMethod [as render] (http://hostserver/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=true:9036:22)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (http://hostserver/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=true:22776:28)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (http://hostserver/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=true:22802:24)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._updateRenderedComponent (http://hostserver/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=true:22728:30)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._performComponentUpdate (http://hostserver/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=true:22708:6)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.updateComponent (http://hostserver/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=true:22627:6)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.receiveComponent (http://hostserver/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=true:22527:6)
```

Comment: As the actual error details are not available in the pasted log, the only probable reason I'd think of is that maybe the geocoder requires throttling the calls. With the code above, the calls will queue up to be executed as fast as possible. If this is indeed the case (which you can ascertain by looking at the error details in catch), you can simply de-bounce the API calls. Or use a sequence instead.

Comment: The last few lines on the official docs https://github.com/devfd/react-native-geocoder do mention sequential execution order needs on iOS. If you are doing this in Android with Gooogle API fallback, it definitely starts to throttle, but not so fast.

Comment: Also, shouldn't getLocation return a Promise instead of json?

Comment: Yes it's also part of the problem, but the main question is getting any response at all from Geocoder.

Comment: Try removing the `getLocations` await - `annotations: locations.map(this.getLocation)`. My theory is that since `getLocation` is not returning a Promise, the `Promise.all` breaks down. And additionally iOS is restricting parallel geocode invocations. With the suggested change, the invocations will become sequential.

Comment: It didn't work yet. I tried the example, which uses `then` and still nothing returned: `getLocation(location) {
     Geocoder.geocodeAddress(location.address).then(res => {
       return (
            {
                latitude: res[0].position.lat,
                longitude: res[0].position.lng,
                title: location.provider,
                subtitle: location.address,
            }
       );
     }).catch(err => console.log(err));
  }`

Comment: @HazardouS: `getLocation` *does* return a promise, it's an `async` method.

Comment: @Bergi: The examples of asyncs I saw so far explicitly return a Promise instance, or await. Do you mean having an async against a function auto-wraps the return into a Promise?

Comment: @HazardouS: Yes, it wraps the whole function execution in a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the geocode API might not support concurrent requests. Try to batch them:

```
async getLocations(locations) {
  Geocoder.fallbackToGoogle(GEOCODE_API_KEY);
  const annotations = []
  for (const l of locations) {
    const r = await this.getLocation(l)
    if (r == null) continue; // or display error message or whatever
    annotations.push(r)
    this.setState({annotations}); // move this after the loop if you want only one update
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution that has batch geocoding built in you could try a service like the SmartyStreets US Street Address API. Currently, there is also an International Street Address API, but it doesn't offer batch built in. You can read more about it [here](https://smartystreets.com/docs/us-street-api)

Disclaimer: I work for SmartyStreets